# Get the values from php using ajax when loading page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to PHP and Ajax. Below is my index.html code for redirects to details.php when click on search found values in search box :

```
$(document).on('click', '.foundValue', function(){

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                window.location.href = 'php/details.php?id='+id; 

});
```

details.php code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                   var id = '<?php echo($id);?>';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/getBiodata.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'id=' + id,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#biodata').html(response);
                }
            });
          });
```

After page loads response not getting from php but, when i used same code in index.html to get the data from same file it was woring as per expectation. I need to redirect to another page when click in index page.I have to get some other details also from different files. Is this correct way to do this? If its a correct way to do, where i did mistake. Thanks!

Below is my getBioData.php code:

```
<?php
    //require('utility/database.php');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

//Connect to Database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $return = array();
    $query="select * from biodata where ID = '$id'";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
            $firstName =$row['FIRST_NAME'];
            $lastName=$row['LAST_NAME'];
            $fatherName =$row['FATHER_NAME'];


            echo "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>First Name</div>
                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>: ".$firstName."</div>
                 </div>";
            echo "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>Last Name</div>
                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>: ".$lastName."</div>
                 </div>";
            echo "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>Father Name</div>
                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>: ".$fatherName."</div>
                 </div>";

}

?>
```

Search box code:

```
$('#users').typeahead({
                name: 'user',
                template:['<div class="media br-bottom foundValue" id="{{ID}}">',
                          '<a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-rounded" width="35" height="35" src="{{image_url}}"></a>',
                          '<div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading">{{FIRST_NAME}},{{LAST_NAME}}</h4>',
                          '<p>{{PLACE_BIRTH}}<p></div></div>'
                          ].join(''),
                engine: Hogan,
                remote: 'search.php?query=%QUERY'
            });
```

Comment: Since you are calling `$id=$_GET['id'];`, you will need to change `type: 'post'` to `type: 'get'` in your ajax call

Comment: Thanks for your reply! First i have used get but it was not working, then i have changed to test.

Comment: at the top of `details.php` and this line `<?php $id= isset( $_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;  ?>` , if you dont have that already. of course, you may not need the php tags depending on where you put it

Comment: i have used <?php $id=$_GET['id'] ?> code in details.php and i have debugged jquery code using fire bug, id value coming as expected.

Comment: what is the value of `id` when it gets to your jquery?

Comment: Actually its a search box. When we are entering the letters it searches the values and displays. Adding individual id to the <div> which is getting from database. When i click on search found value it should redirect to other page and display the related details which has to get from different php files.I have added my search box code at my quetion.

Comment: Same file working if i put it outside folder. In my project folder inside php files are not working properly. Can any one please let me know how to use inside folder php files,Thanks.

Comment: In your sql query, aren't you searching for $id as a string in place of $id as variable. Correct it using '". $id."'";